# Unity clone objects don't include scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anybody know how can I include scripts when my objects clone. In my game, I need to make that when my ball hit moving wall, then there is need to show new wall including my moving scripts. MY CASE: new wall is shown, but it is not moving.

Please help. 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is not on your prefab (for any reason), you can add via a script:

```
void CreateWall(){
    GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(wallPrefab);
    NewScript ns = obj.AddComponent<NewScript>();
}
```

The only advantage I could think about that way is that you can add specific components based on a specific situation. Say you want to add Script A if condition A or Script B if condition B:

```
void CreateWall(){
    GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(wallPrefab);
    switch(condition){
         case A:
         obj.AddComponent<ScriptA>();
         break;
         case B:
         obj.AddComponent<ScriptB>();
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it helps :)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is very easy.

First case: if you are using the prefab to instantiate, be sure to assign on the prefab your scripts.

Second case: if you are taking the template to instantiate directly from GameObject of wall, it should create the GameObject with exatly same scripts.

If it is still not moving, check in Inspector the cloned wall, if the scripts are enabled, and double check how the scripts work (maybe needs some initializing or whatever)